# getSummaryCount() and getItemsCount() returns the same value

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, cart

I am trying to get the item quantity in the cart. 
For that I am using:
`Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getItemsCount()`
and
`Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount()`
 `getSummaryCount()` is what I really need, but it always returns the same value as `getItemsCount()`. For example: If I would have two of the same item in my basket, both functions would return `1`. (I want it to return `2`) 
 
 Why could this be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below.

```
Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getItemsQty();
```

Comment: Great, thanks, this works! (I'll accept the answer as soon as it allows me to, have to wait 5 minutes).